# NotImplementedError: QgsPluginLayer.setTransformContext() is abstract and must be overridden

Tags: python, openstreetmap, google-maps

I keep trying to load Google Maps to start a project and I keep getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError: QgsPluginLayer.setTransformContext() is abstract and must be overridden
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: How do you try to load Google Maps base map to the project? Using a plugin?

Comment: I tried using the web feature. I ended up installing additional maps services  and it worked :)